# Why is the css nth-child doesn't work for the last second element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the example below it is the 4th element which is not aligned according to the css.

```js
$( "span" ).each(function( index ) {
  
  $(".edit").append('<input class="inputtext" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() +
 '" name="'+index+'" id="input_'+$(this).attr("id")+'"/></br>');
  });

  
  $('.inputtext').on('keyup',function(){
    var abc = $(this).val();
    console.log(abc);
    var id= $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    $('#'+id).text(abc);
});
```

```css
.editable:nth-child(1) {
  top:10px;
  left:50px;
}

.editable:nth-child(2){
  top:30px;
  left:50px;
}
  
.editable:nth-child(3) {
  top:60px;
  left:50px;
}

.editable:nth-child(4) {
  top:90px;
  left:50px;
}

.editable:last-child {
  top:120px;
  left:50px;
}

.text {
  color:#FFFFFF; 
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  padding:5px;
}

.photoStyle {
  height:500px;
  width:600px;
}

.edit {
  border:2px solid black;
  width:600px;
}

.inputtext {
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <img src="http://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/stltoday.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/8/12/8126e948-17fe-5102-b12f-908660e0f7e4/57d981d98e495.image.jpg?resize=1200%2C679" class="photoStyle" />
   
    <span class="text editable" id="t1">1</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t2">2</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t3">3</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t4">4</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t5">5</span> 
</div>

<div class="edit"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working correctly. The rule is saying, an element with class of `editable` that is the 4th element under the parent. The first child is the `img`, not the first `span`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't taking the `img` element, which is the 1st-child in that group, into account. Adjust your numbers by one and it works.

```js
$( "span" ).each(function( index ) {
  
  $(".edit").append('<input class="inputtext" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() +
 '" name="'+index+'" id="input_'+$(this).attr("id")+'"/></br>');
  });

  
  $('.inputtext').on('keyup',function(){
    var abc = $(this).val();
    console.log(abc);
    var id= $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    $('#'+id).text(abc);
});
```

```css
.editable { left:50px; }
.editable:nth-child(2) { top:10px; }
.editable:nth-child(3) { top:30px; }
.editable:nth-child(4) { top:60px; }
.editable:nth-child(5) { top:90px; color:yellow;}
.editable:last-child { top:120px; }

.text {
  color:#FFFFFF; 
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  padding:5px;
}

.photoStyle {
  height:500px;
  width:600px;
}

.edit {
  border:2px solid black;
  width:600px;
}

.inputtext { height:25px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <img src="http://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/stltoday.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/8/12/8126e948-17fe-5102-b12f-908660e0f7e4/57d981d98e495.image.jpg?resize=1200%2C679" class="photoStyle" />
   
    <span class="text editable" id="t1">1</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t2">2</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t3">3</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t4">4</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t5">5</span> 
</div>

<div class="edit"></div>
```

**You could also wrap just the `<span>` elements in their own `<div>` and keep all the numbers as they were and it would work since the `img` would no longer be a child in that group.**

```
<div class="menu">
    <img src="http://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/stltoday.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/8/12/8126e948-17fe-5102-b12f-908660e0f7e4/57d981d98e495.image.jpg?resize=1200%2C679" class="photoStyle" />

  <!-- By wrapping all the spans in their own div, the numbers work as expected. -->
  <div>
    <span class="text editable" id="t1">1</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t2">2</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t3">3</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t4">4</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t5">5</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the position of your elements, you can use `:nth-of-type(x)` to select them.

here `:nth-child(1)` refers to the image :)

```css
.editable {
  left:50px;
 }

.editable:nth-of-type(1) {
  top:10px;
}

.editable:nth-of-type(2){
  top:30px;
}
  
.editable:nth-of-type(3) {
  top:60px;
}

.editable:nth-of-type(4) {
  top:90px;
}

.editable:nth-of-type(5) {
  top:120px;
}

.text {
  color:#FFFFFF; 
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  padding:5px;
}

.photoStyle {
  height:500px;
  width:600px;
}

.edit {
  border:2px solid black;
  width:600px;
}

.inputtext {
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <img src="http://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/stltoday.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/8/12/8126e948-17fe-5102-b12f-908660e0f7e4/57d981d98e495.image.jpg?resize=1200%2C679" class="photoStyle" />
   
    <span class="text editable" id="t1">1</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t2">2</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t3">3</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t4">4</span> 
    <span class="text editable" id="t5">5</span> 
</div>

<div class="edit"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That 4th `.editable` span doesn't match any of your CSS selectors, because it is actually the 5th child of its parent.  The `img` element is the first child there.

If you wanted to redo this so it only depends on the other `.editable` elements, you could do:

```
.editable {top:10px; left:50px;}
.editable + .editable {top:30px;}
.editable + .editable + .editable {top:60px;}
.editable + .editable + .editable + .editable {top:90px;}
.editable + .editable + .editable + .editable + .editable {top:120px;}
```

using the `+` ([adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)).